# rugarch won't open thanks to Rzlib.dll

Tags: r

I updated my R from version 3.1 to 3.2. After moving all my packages to the correct library I was going to use the `rugarch` package and when I type `library(rugarch)` I got a message that my computer didn't have Rzlib.dll and the package can't be load. Problem that I just get with this package.
I have already reinstall R and the package `rugarch` like 3 times both and didn't work and search on the net but didn't get anything useful.

Comment: When you upgrade R version, you have to run `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`. Did you? Also, if you installed Rtools, you probably have to upgrade it too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment it work perfectly, I didn’t know that I had to do that every time I updated my R, even though I read somethings before doing it I think I miss it. Thanks for the grammar corrections also, English is not my first language.